Manually formatting date tick labels using pgfplots
I want to make the plots in PGF/TikZ for my publications. I need to format the date ticks manually (see example from Matplotlib documentation).
I define a start date (xmin) and an end date (xmax); in between, I want to arrange major ticks (interval 24 months) and minor ticks (for each month).
I ask for your help and hope someone has already solved this problem and would like to share it here.

MWE:
\documentclass[11pt, tikz, crop, varwidth=250mm, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
% LEGEND % 
legend style = {at={(0.9,0.9)}, legend columns=3, anchor=east, font=\tiny, draw=none, inner sep =0pt},
%
tick label style={font=\small},
label style={font=\small},
title style={font=\small},
%
width = 8.0cm, height = 6cm,
%
tick style={thin},
minor tick style ={thin},
%
date coordinates in = x,
xticklabel=\year-\month,
date ZERO = 2021-01-01,
xmin = 2021-01-01,
xmax = 2023-12-01,
xticklabel style = {anchor=north east, rotate=45},
%
% I don't want do manually "bake" the ticks into the plot
xtick={2021-01-01, 2021-07-01, 2022-01-01, 2022-07-01, 2023-01-01, 2023-07-01, 2023-12-01},
%
ylabel = {Distance},
ymin=-0, ymax=6,
ytick={0, 1.0, ..., 6.0},  
xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,  
]

\addplot[color=black, solid, thick]
table[x=date, y=value, col sep=comma]{data.txt};
\addlegendentry{data}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Data:
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
    date, value
    2021-01-01, 2.072457
    2021-02-01, 2.209934
    2021-03-01, 2.588002
    2021-04-01, 2.498113
    2021-05-01, 2.214694
    2021-06-01, 2.242065
    2021-07-01, 2.197125
    2021-08-01, 1.948843
    2021-09-01, 1.945804
    2021-10-01, 2.077016
    2021-11-01, 2.501014
    2021-12-01, 2.813076
    2022-01-01, 2.848438
    2022-02-01, 2.994862
    2022-03-01, 3.425982
    2022-04-01, 3.744854
    2022-05-01, 3.407557
    2022-06-01, 3.402444
    2022-07-01, 3.748655
    2022-08-01, 3.529377
    2022-09-01, 3.733859
    2022-10-01, 3.890095
    2022-11-01, 3.357926
    2022-12-01, 3.468896
    2023-01-01, 3.689547
    2023-02-01, 3.976246
    2023-03-01, 3.889607
    2023-04-01, 3.884615
    2023-05-01, 4.281348
    2023-06-01, 4.085681
    2023-07-01, 4.429838
    2023-08-01, 4.700875
    2023-09-01, 4.960294
    2023-10-01, 5.18179
    2023-11-01, 5.327941
    2023-12-01, 5.459256
\end{filecontents*}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

I hope this helps!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
% LEGEND %
legend style = {at={(0.9,0.9)}, legend columns=3, anchor=east, font=\tiny, draw=none, inner sep =0pt},
%
tick label style={font=\small},
label style={font=\small},
title style={font=\small},
%
width = 8.0cm, height = 6cm,
%
tick style={thin},
minor tick style ={thin},
%
date coordinates in = x,
xticklabel=\year-\month,
date ZERO = 2021-01-01,
xmin = 2021-01-01,
xmax = 2024-01-01,
xticklabel style = {anchor=north east, rotate=45},
%
%%%%% the changes %%%%%%
minor x tick num=24,
xtick distance=365,
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
ylabel = {Distance},
ymin=-0, ymax=6,
ytick={0, 1.0, ..., 6.0},
xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,
]

\addplot[color=black, solid, thick]
table[x=date, y=value, col sep=comma]{data.txt};
\addlegendentry{data}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I hope this helps! Please provide some MWE for a complete answer.

Thanks for your quick answer, the minor ticks are not visible if I use this solution? Any idea?

Thanks for providing the MWE; I have updated my answer to reflect the same.

Thank you for your update. Is it somehow possible to take leap years into account?
If I have a data set that spans 10 years, for example, the ticks after the leap year are one month wrong.

For small number of years (say 10), a bad yet working hack can be to simply use xtick distance=366 for all. :P
